# Broken History in IOS7

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, ios7, backbone-routing

I'm building SPA(single page app) using Backbone(1.1.2) and Jquery Mobile(1.4.2), and I'm experiencing strange things when browsing web site  with IPhone( running IOS7,lower versions work just fine) , basically my app just won't load.. it has some issues with history..

When I put site on home screen it seems that is working just fine..I have tested this site on many other devices and Operating Systems such as: all Android versions, Windows Phone 8, Blackberry, even Symbian..

How much I was able to understand this is deliberated restriction from Apple. Does anyone has workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite simple .. I just needed to **disable private browsing** in safari, which is how it seems by default **enabled**. I hope this is will help someone in future.